# What is the code for keyboard to make it type in proper case always

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to modify android keyboard so that it always types in proper case i,e the first letter of each word is in uppercase like this " This Is A Sample Text" Which code should I put and where. Please help me.

I changed android: inputType="textCapSentences" to textCapWords everywhere,  still keyboard is typing in sentence case case, How can i make it type in Proper case always.
Please Help!
Thank You

*I tried to modify this app using apk editor,  I don't have PC and Android Studio*

Answer (score 0):

Use textCapCharacters.  Although note this is only a hint to the keyboard and may not be enforced.  It depends on the keyboard app itself (same with all the other modes)

Comment: I used textCapCharacters also but keyboard is still typing in sentence case. I want to force my keyboard to type the first letter of each word in upper case  like this " How Are You"

Comment: That wouldn't be CapCharacters, that would be CapWord.  And you can't force a keyboard to do anything.  It's a separate app, and can do what it wants.  All you can do is request.  If you want to force it, you need to use a TextWatcher to wait for the text to be set by the keyboard, then change it into what you want.